# Pods-resources.sh Permission denied in iOS Project

Tags: ios, permission-denied, xcode5.0.1

I have got an existing project from a client and I tried to run this in my MAC using XCode 5.0

But I am facing this following error. I installed Cocoa Pods but still doesn't work. This project is running fine in other developer's machine. I badly need this running in my machine.

What I am missing?

[image]

Comment: i had the same issue

Comment: Note to future readers: Do not post images of error messages. Post the error message as text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You need to make the script executable. Open terminal and execute this command:

```
chmod a+x "/Users/shovon0203/Desktop/My Work/oDesk/momenTOGO/MomenTOGO_iPhone/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"
```

Comment: your command works but not from Terminal :P, i edit the pods script and use the above command and now its working :) thanks dude!

Comment: This happens to me when I start a new project, install pods on my home computer then continue the project on my laptop. Is there any way to set the frameworks.sh default permission so I won't have to do this in the terminal everytime I transfer my project between my home and work computers? Thanks

Comment: Running the above command along with "sudo" resolved the issue.

Comment: Since I'm using Subversion with my project this was only a temporary solution because when any other person would initially check out this file, the execute rights would be lost again. use `svn propset svn:executable '*' <file>` to fix this.

Comment: I tried this command and it didnt work. Then i tried the command with sudo which also didnt work. Then i added a User-defined-setting to the build settings in xcode "PODS_ROOT = ${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods/". This is what fixed it for me. It seems the Permission denied error was quite misleading because the script was actually not able to find the file.

Comment: This, @Kevin, saved my life. I've worked on an app for 6 month and switched to a new MacBook Pro. Suddenly that "permission denied" thing popped up and this did the job. Thank you!

Comment: I was facing same issue in my Azure Dev Ops pipeline and finally fix it by adding this command in my pre-build script, Thanks @kevin you saved my day

Comment: Still works with terminal!

Answer (score 60):

Try this, Works like a charm!

```
rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock
pod install
```

Comment: This worked for me, but no need to remove the `Podfile.lock` file.

Comment: this should be marked as the solution.

Comment: this is the correct answer. when you create the pods no writes issues

Comment: Thank you, I had this issue when restoring a dead Macbook Pro's backup to it's replacement machine and had these permission errors

Answer (score 24):

for me deintegrating all pods then reinstalling them did the trick:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 18):

Running `pod install` in the main project directory where your podfile is located should solve the problem

Answer (score 15):

You need to make the script executable. Open terminal and execute this command:

```
chmod a+x "your_path(where show permission denied)"
```

Please check if there no any space in folder name then add '\' before

Answer (score 9):

This steps worked for me after failing many times.

STEP 1: Navigate to the location of the folder containing Pods-resources.sh

STEP 2: Open the terminal type cd and then drag the folder containing Pods-resources.sh to terminal and hit enter.

STEP 3: the run this command>> chmod a+x Pods-resources.sh

STEP 4: restart xcode and open your xxx.xworkspace

STEP 5: enjoy

Comment: After long searching about this issue, this one works perfectly in my case. One correction is when run the command then please follow this: chmod a+x Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh

Comment: Good to hear, nice coding.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all && rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install
```

It always works well in my projects.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the folder `Pods-[Your_Project_Name]` completely and do fresh `pod install`

Answer (score 3):

The above answer works. However, I had the same issue, but it was recurring. It dealt with having the same branch checked-out on multiple machines. It would work on one machine, and not the others. We use TFS as our source control (it's ok, you can judge), which does not play nicely with `.sh`, `.py`, etc. files. We had to add a `.tpattributes` file to every directory with a `.sh` or `.py` file in it so we could run `.sh` and `.py` files as executables.

Entries in the `.tpattributes` file looks like this:

```
Pods-MyTarget-frameworks.sh:x
Pods-MyTarget-resources.sh:x
```

This translates to `chmod +x "Pods-MyTarget-frameworks.sh"`

Works like a charm!

Comment: where you've placed: `.tpattributes` file ?

Comment: In Pods > Target Support Files > Pods-[Target Name]

Comment: thanks, added but still getting [the following issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BpWRnIuAXPeWtpMHNNSVlrQVU/view?usp=sharing) . What anything else do you suggest? (P.S. - [here's the content of the script](https://gist.github.com/alexszilagyi/e0db78298d0719b4f75fffe78eef661e) & [here](https://gist.github.com/alexszilagyi/e0db78298d0719b4f75fffe78eef661e#file-pods-target-resources-sh-L7) it crashes)

Comment: @tentmaking I am just now running into the same issue with TFS. Can you provide a little more info on how you fixed this please?

Comment: @steventnorris We added a file (.tpattributes) to each Pods-[Target] directory (found inside Pods > Target Support Files > Pods-[Target] which has the entry seen in my answer above. Not sure what other info you need.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this as a comment to Kevins answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19687227/3114383. But I thought I might as well put it as an answer because people will find it easier like this and it solved my problem. It might work for others aswell :D

I tried running the chmod command from kevins answer and it didnt work. Then i tried the command with sudo which also didnt work. Then i added a User-defined-setting to the build settings in xcode "PODS_ROOT = ${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods/". This is what fixed it for me. It seems the Permission denied error was quite misleading because the script was actually not able to find the file.

Comment: Hi @CantThink! Could you provide an example on how you added this setting?

Comment: @Gehlen You can define these kind of settings in the xcode build settings section. See https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/xcode-build-settings-user-defined-settings-manage-multiple-environments-with-single-target-3e5c1a307999

Comment: Than you @CantThink, very elusive!

Comment: Hi @CantThinkOfAnyThing! Yes, I did! But in my case I was configuring CI on bamboo, and the problem was that I was trying to access $TMPDIR on Build Phases, so I have no access.. I just remove it and works! Thank you anyway !

Comment: @Gehlen glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case
try this
delete pod.lockfile
clean all builds

1. pod deintegrate
2. pod install
3. flutter run

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue. What I've done is:

1. Create a brand new project with same name and same package name
2. In the terminal of the project directory Pod init
3. Open the pod file in a editor
4. Copy and paste the old project pod files into the new one
5. Copy all files and resources to the new project
6. Simply do `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem with  Pods-project-frameworks.sh, resolved by removing first line `#!/bin/sh` from Pods-project-frameworks.sh file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **Pods** folder and **Podfile.lock** from **ios** folder then try to re-run

Answer (score 0):

In the build phase you have to add `chmod +x` in front of the commands. For example, in my case I added following command in my **[CP] Copy Pod Resources** phase,

> chmod +x "${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-resources.sh"