# Xcode won't run transferred project: "Pods-App1/Pods-App1-frameworks.sh: Permission denied"

Tags: xcode, permissions, cocoapods

I recently got a new Mac, and I sent my Xcode project to it via Dropbox(copy and paste). However, when I try to debug and run it, it comes out with this error: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lq4S.png)

I installed cocoa pods, and I'm running Os x Capitan.

Help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687033/pods-resources-sh-permission-denied-in-ios-project

Comment: I do not believe it to be a duplicate, the errors are located on different files.