# How can I fix this error about the shell script invocation Error in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift2

[image]

I'm using swift2.2 to develop this app, I want to update this code of app to swift3 and I get this error. Also, I can not fix this error, I have no idea to fix this. Please help me.Thank you!!

Comment: is this duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687227/4834226

Comment: I try this that this is not work for me. Thank you. I use the following command.

Comment: chmod a+x "/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/iOS/PROJECTNAME/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-frameworks.sh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. I need to reinstall/update the new podfile data.
I'm create a new project and copy the word of podfile to old podfile. Also, open the Terminal and cd to the old project path and "pod update".

MARK: you will be careful that if you're having the framework in the old podfile.

I hold this solution can help you