# Any Way to Run a project with Pod files Where Cocoa-pods is not Installed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I have Mini mac With standard user rights. It don't have any cocoa pods installed on it. I want to run a project that contains pod files in it. When i Try to run it says

```
/Users/XXXXXXX-XXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-hkrwfroyuxqvcrecstbfqzyxetsv/Build/Intermediates/XXXX.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXXX.build/Script-5A7AA4516827BE2CA0B5E393.sh: line 2: /Users/XXXXXXX-XXXX/Downloads/IOS_APP_R3.2/XXXX/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXX/Pods-XXXX-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
```

**Note** I can't install cocoa pods on mac as i don't have sudo access.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687033/pods-resources-sh-permission-denied-in-ios-project

Comment: Thanks @mag_zbc for userull comment. i have flagged it usefull :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

1- take note of all the pod files installed (on notepad).

2- Remove all pods and dependencies of it (many errors will appear since you're using non existing libraries).

3- get each library from the internet (most of them should be from Github) and import their libraries manually to the application.

This should do the trick in your situation!